# How to calculate a total in a grid with breeze.js extended entities?

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js, breeze, computed-observable

I am working on an MVC web application using the MVVM pattern, breeze.js and knockout.js. This is the first time I use these js libraries and I still have to grasp how they work.

One of the pages of the application has a grid where both columns and rows are generated dynamically. I need to add an additional column where for each row I have the total of values displayed in the following row cells. Here an example:

```
Data type |   Comment   |  Fact 1 | Fact 2 |  Total    | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4
==============================================================================================
Item 1    | any comment |  fact 1 | fact 2 | calc. sum |    10   |   20    |    30   |   40
```

The grid is generated by binding a breeze entity object (planningItems) to templates. The object has the properties DataTypeId, Comment, Member, Total, FactValues. Total is the calculated sum.

```
<script type="text/html" id="list-planning-template">
<tr data-bind="mouseOverButton: $data">
    <td style="text-align: center">
        <button class="actionbutton actionbutton-item" data-bind="selectItem: $root.selectedItems, itemId: FactId"></button>
    </td>
    <td data-bind="text: DataTypeId" />
    <td data-bind="text: Comment().Text" />
    <!-- ko foreach: FactMembers -->
    <td data-bind="text: Member().Code"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <td data-bind="text: Total" />
    <!-- ko foreach: FactValues -->
    <td style="width: 50px" data-bind="text: Value"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
```

I have been trying to add the Total property by extending the breeze entity object in the following way:

```
var FactCtor = function () {
this.Total = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var sum = 0;
        if (this.FactValues) {
            this.FactValues().forEach(function (fv) {
                sum += fv.Value();
            });
        }
        return sum;
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
}, this);
};

manager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Fact", FactCtor);
```

Essentially, what this code is supposed to do is to extend the entity by adding a knockout computed observable named Total with deferred evaluation. The function iterates through the breeze observable array FactValues and adds the values. I have been mucking about different versions of this code to no avail. Can anyone give me a hint on what is wrong with this code?

Comment: My **suspicion** is that the computed is not triggered by changes within the array or to its contents. The computed is only triggered by changes to the `FactValues` property itself. The `FactValues` is an array. It's always the same array even when the array *contents* change. I'm just guessing as I said. If my guess is correct, there is a way forward … by listening for changes to the array (adds/removes) and triggering the refresh of the computed when values come or go. You might try that. I'm swamped at the moment but if someone hasn’t solved it in a day or so I'll give it love.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ward. We were able to overcome the problem by using a custom binding. Please see my follow-up post for details.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

We were not able to get the code posted in my previous post to work. We were eventually able to overcome the problem by using a custom binding with breeze. Here is the code:

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.getFyTotal = {
   update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
       var sum = 0;
       var fact = valueAccessor();
       if (fact.FactValues()) {
           fact.FactValues().forEach(function (fv) {
               sum += parseFloat(fv.Value());
           });
       }

       $(element).html(sum);
   }
};
```

The custom binding is then referenced in the HTML code the following way:

```
<td data-bind="getFyTotal: $data" />
```

Hope this may help others.

**REVISED VERSION:**

We have updated the above code to take advantage of ko.utils functions:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.getFyTotal = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var sum = 0;
    var fact = valueAccessor();
    if (fact.FactValues()) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(fact.FactValues(), function (fv) {
            sum += parseFloat(fv.Value());
        });
    }

    $(element).html(sum);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I modeled your code outside of Breeze and it's working:

http://jsfiddle.net/DazWilkin/yGZ7g/7/

I made a small tweak of adding a reference to FactValues (observableArray) on your constructor to overcome what - I believe - is the looping/this issue in JavaScript.

However, I haven't tried this in Breeze and wanted to do something similar. I was unable to get a similar function working and ultimately, created the totals during the 'then' processing of my executeQuery:

```
...manager.executeQuery(....).then(function(data) {
   ...
   Fact.Total(FactValues()
      .map(function(fv){ return fv.Value(); })
      .reduce(function (total,curr) { return total+curr; });
   ...
}
```

I will try to get back to working on my version of this today and, if I find a better solution, I'll report back.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, DazWilkin. It's interesting that the code works for you. In our case it fails when breeze attempts to query the data. Eventually we resolved the problem by using a custom binding with breeze. See the update in my original post for details.